# Как сформулировать запрос «select колонки, подзапрос(count())» в CriteriaQuery?

Tags: sql, jpa, criteria

Сейчас работает вариант с join, но хочу избавиться от group by в запросе.
Как сделать запрос с подзапросом количества в select?

```
SELECT
   t.id, t.title,
   (SELECT COUNT(t2.t2_id)
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE (t2.t2_id = t.id))
FROM table1 t
```

Comment: _хочу избавиться от group by в запросе_ Во-первых - зачем? во-вторых, в Вашем запросе нет GROUP BY... И вообще - какой смысл в одном наборе данных получать данные разных уровней группировки?

Comment: У таблицы `t` добавьте поле (напр. t2_count), в котором храните количество записей по внешнему ключу из таблицы `t2`. При добавлении записей или удалении из таблицы `t2` обновляйте соответсвующее поле в таблице `t`. Таким образом вы избавитесь от подзапроса.

Answer (score 0):

вариант с join и group by - на мой взгляд - самый лучший. если нет конкретной необходимости избавляться от  join'а и group by - тогда оставьте!

Answer (score 0):

// Не понятка при создании вопроса, я автор

Это текущий используемый запрос с groupBy, обрезан.
Есть еще запрос на количество Project для постраничной навигации.
С join получается не равное количество записей.

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Project> cq = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
    Root<Project> root = cq.from(Project.class);

    Join atts = root.join("attachments", JoinType.LEFT);

    cq.select(
            cb.construct(
                    Project.class,
                    root.get("id"),
                    root.get("regDate"),
                    // другие поля
                    cb.count(atts)
            )
    )
            .groupBy(root); // ============== groupBy

    TypedQuery<Project> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снимается.
Ошибка в коде. Оказалось что в запрос выборки количество проектов всего включился left join root.join("attachments" что и создавало ошибку не равенства.
Под запрос более не нужен.
В любом случае спасибо.